# Am learning basic java and i got wrong output

Tags: java

In the code below I am trying to convert char to int. Then I want to print the value of b, but I am getting 155 as output.

```
public class Maths {

    static int age = 39, age2 = 49;

    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        int a = 's';
        int b = a;
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: And what are you expecting, if not the ascii value of 's' ?

Comment: I find your English very unclear.  Would it be possible for you to tidy up your grammar a little?  Also, are you _sure_ you're getting 155?  I don't see how that's possible.  I voted to close as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: ASCII value of `'s'` is actually 115.  Is that what you meant rather than 155?

Comment: Yes , its 115 not 155. It's taking ASCII value.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this for printing your character 's' and 115 both:

```
public class cn{


    static int age=39 , age2=49 ;

     public static void main (String Args[])

            {
            int a='s'; // Storing ASCII of 's' i.e. 115
            int b=a; // Coping 115 in b


            System.out.printf("%c\n",a); // to print s using char literal
            System.out.println(b); // this print 115

        }
    }
```

In your code you are initializing `int` with a `char` that is storing `ASCII` of `'s'(115)` and then you copied that in b so the value in b is 115.

Comment: Note that you could print `a` or `b`, those are the same values.

Comment: There is no difference between those to `int`, that's my point.