# Basic Java : why am getting output as 115 and S , for below program

Tags: java

```
public class Maths
{

    public static void main (String Args[])
    {
        char a= "b";
        char b="a";


        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

Here  getting output as 115 and S

Comment: why are you not getting compilation error ?

Comment: You should use a single quotation.

Comment: Welcome to java world. Go through link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: Please paste the program for which you are actually getting the output `115` and `S`. You showed us the wrong program because this program doesn't compile. Even if it is fixed by changing the double quotes to single quotes you will not get that output. Easy mistake to make: you just pasted the wrong program.

Comment: This code [doesn't even compile](http://rextester.com/VKA94901).  Please show us the actual code you ran to get this output.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen , Can you please explain why this code wont compile.

Comment: it won 't compile cause u need to declare your chars like         char a= 'b';
        char b='a';

Comment: With double quotes you declare a `String` in Java and you can't cast from `String` to `char`, even if it's a single letter.

Answer (score 0):

You still get the output from your [old code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47713810/8097737).

First of all it's crucial to look at the output from `javac` when you compile your code. (Or the warnings and errors from the IDE).

Thanks to [`@Tim Biegeleisen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807111/basic-java-why-am-getting-output-as-115-and-s-for-below-program/47807626#comment82575549_47807111) for the [compiler-error](http://rextester.com/VKA94901).

```
Error(s), warning(s):

source_file.java:11: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char
                char a= "b";
                        ^
source_file.java:12: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char
        char b="a";
               ^
2 errors
```

Then you would have seen that this code doesn't compile, because you try to assign a `String`-value into a `char`-variable.

The correct way to assign a value to a `char` is:

```
char a = 'a';
```

---

By the way: When you changed the program-output and it still prints the old value, clean the bin-folder and compile it again. When the folder remains empty than you have a compile-error and need to look on the output from `javac` to see the reason.